# Connecting to PPPOE ethernet over USB to ethernet adapter

Tags: usb, pppoe

I have an ASUS Infinity tablet, running Android 4.1.1.

I plugged in my USB to Ethernet adapter, and it said that the ethernet port was detected. How do I set up my ISP username and password?